# WPF Calculator with more than One Operator at a Time not working

Tags: c#, wpf, operators, calculator

The Code is still unfinished but the Main problem I keep getting stuck on are the Operators. I have one Method for all my Operators but I can only use on Operator at a Time. Whenever the second Operator get pressed he overwrites the first one.

Even in a Calculation with 2 or more Operators he will just use the last value he got.

Here is the Code and please don´t mind the Operators "x² and sqrt(".

Thank you all in advance

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string Input = " ";
        string Operator = null;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Width;
            this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height;
        }

        private void Number_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Input = " ";

            Button button = (Button)sender;
            Input += button.Content.ToString();
            Equation.Text += button.Content.ToString();
        }

        private void Operator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Operator))
            {
                Operator += button.Content.ToString();
                Input = " ";
            }

            Operator = button.Content.ToString();
            Equation.Text += button.Content.ToString();
        }

        private void b_equal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Equation.Text = Calculon(Operator);
        }
        private string Calculon(string Operator)
        {
            double Result = 0;
            string Error = "Syntaxfehler";
            string[] Text = Equation.Text.Split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length - 2;)
            {
                double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Text[i]);
                double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Text[i + 2]);

                if (Operator == " x ")
                {
                    Result = numberOne * numberTwo;
                }

                if (Operator == " - ")
                {
                    Result = numberOne - numberTwo;
                }

                if (Operator == " + ")
                {
                    Result = numberOne + numberTwo;
                }

                if (Operator == " / ")
                {
                    Result = numberOne / numberTwo;
                }

                if (Operator == " ² ")
                {
                    Result = Math.Round(numberOne,2);
                }

                if (Operator == " sqrt( ")
                {
                    Result = Math.Sqrt(numberOne);
                }
               
                i += 2;

                Text[i] = Result.ToString();

            }
            if (Result.Equals(double.NaN))
            {
               return Error;
            }
            return Result.ToString();
        }
        private void b_Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Equation.Text = null;
        }

        private void bpunkt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Equation.Text += ",";
        }
    }
```

I tried to make to Operator Values, like Operator1 and operator2. It works but when I have more than two we have the same problem again.

Also a loop was in my mind but there for the string has to be already completed so that also didn´t work cause the method activates everytime you press an operator button.

Comment: Do you intend to evaluate complex expressions, like `(1+2)*3`? Similarly to a graphing calculator or windows calculator? or just handle simple one or two value expressions, like `1+2`? similar to a old, simple, cheap calculator?

Comment: I need to evaluate complex expression, also sqrt and x²

Comment: Then you need to parse the expression into a tree before evaluation. Simply processing tokens left to right is not enough. There is a whole lot of complexity regarding things like order of operations you need to handle.  Or use [an existing library](https://github.com/matheval/expression-evaluator-c-sharp) that does it for you.

Comment: Thank you I already put all useable operators inside a List. Then I let an foreach loop go trough all of them to check if the operator is in the Equation.